# Help to write the domain in a forma correct way

Tags: calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus, functions

The question is simple: the domain of $f(x, y) = \ln(\sqrt{xy} + 1)$.

Now this is just $xy \geq 0$, which means either $x \geq 0$ and $y \geq 0$ or $y \leq 0$ and $y \leq 0$. This is easy to say and write in this way, but I want to write it in a formal mathematical way. This is what I did:

$$D = \{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 | (x \geq 0, y \geq 0) \cup (x \leq 0, y \leq 0)\}$$

Yet I have some doubts about, since $\cup$ means at least in one of the sets. Maybe it's still correct, and I am confusing the symbol, but $A \cup B$ means that an element $k$ is in $A$ or $B$ or both.

This would make me thing that I could have $x \geq 0$ and $y \leq 0$, which wouldn't be in $D$...

Can you please help me?

Comment: Why not write $D = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : xy \geq 0\}$?

Comment: @Oscar That is what I thought at the beginning, but I wanted to make it the more explicit possible!

Comment: I see... You can also picture $D$ as the axes together with the first quadrant united with the third quadrant. This might be useful terminology... See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrant_(plane_geometry)

Comment: @Oscar Thank you again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fine using comma as a logical "and", more formally we can state that

$$D = \{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 | (x \geq 0  \land y \geq 0) \cup (x \leq 0 \land  y \leq 0)\}$$

or also simply

$$D = \{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 | xy\ge 0\}$$

Comment: Oh, thank you! The logical symbol for "and" is a great touch!